# Xcode and SCM conflict error

Tags: svn, xcode, version-control, conflict

I am getting this following error even though i am the only person working on this project.

```
> Error: 155015 (A conflict in the working copy obstructs the current operation) Description: Commit failed
```

why would this occur as all i keep doing is committing the project every time before do some serious coding. I have committed three times now it is not allowing any more as it throws that error.

Comment: More of a question for Apple Support? Not really a programming question unless this error is being produced by your code.

Comment: Programming questions are not restricted to code. Questions about SCM or SDE are valid programming questions.

Comment: And not a question for Apple as it's a Subversion issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a conflict that needs to be resolved in svn. If it's not one of the files, check if it's a tree conflict.

From the [SVN 1.6 release notes](http://subversion.tigris.org/svn_1.6_releasenotes.html#tree-conflicts):

> Subversion 1.6 recognizes a new kind of conflict, known as a "tree conflict". Such conflicts manifest at the level of directory structure, rather than file content.
>
> Situations now flagged as conflicts include deletions of locally modified files, and incoming edits to locally deleted files. Files and directories which are victims of a tree conflict cannot be committed before the conflict is marked resolved.
>
> Note that Subversion is still treating renames as a "copy+delete" operation, so file renames causing tree conflicts can only be detected in terms of file additions and deletions. Because of this, false positives during tree conflict detection are possible.
>
> To facilitate tree conflict detection, attempting to commit the deletion of a file which has already been deleted in the HEAD revision now causes an error. In Subversion 1.5, this was treated as a no-op, potentially resulting in "empty" revisions which contained no changes.

Comment: Snow Leopard now comes with version 1.6, where Leopard came with 1.4, so he might be hitting this if he just upgraded.

Answer (score 8):

Ok everyone, here's precisely how to solve this problem, assuming your file has the current latest version:

prompt$ svn resolve --accept working **yourfilenamehere**

Resolved conflicted state of **yourfilenamehere**

Then check in normally from the xcode GUI. That's it!

Comment: I am still getting error due to .DS_Store files. How do I remove them there are multiple files of same name?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use a visual client such as [Versions](http://versionsapp.com/) and choose "resolve conflicts" from the menu, which seems to apply the above and other resolution techniques.